# Does race matter?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Is there any differences between races except for looks?

I haven't been able to find any information on this so I am leaning towards it doesn't matter, but I can't find any confirmation on this either.

Comment: That is racist.

Comment: @Wipqozn yes, It took me a while to formulate the question so there was no game related in it and it would still be accepted.

Comment: According to the tool tips Humans are the standard by which the rest of the species are judged.

Comment: Lmfao love this question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bioware have confirmed that there will be "active social" differences between the races, but there isn't anything that will affect the gameplay, just cosmetic differences.

Here's a list of the social abilities as we know of them at the moment:

- **Human** - Rally: Rallies nearby allies.
- **Miraluka** - Sense Force Alignment: Senses the target's alignment with the Force.
- **Twi'lek** - Parlor dance: Perform an unique cultural dance.
- **Zabrak** - Inspire loyalty: Inspires loyalty from nearby allies.
- **Mirialan** - Focusing Ritual: Undergo a focusing ritual to rest and recuperate spirit.
- **Cyborg** - Scan target: Scans target with a critical cybernetic eye.
- **Sith** - Punish: Punish your companion for his or continued failures.
- **Rattataki** - Shadowbox: Perform a series of mock blows, blocks and counters, warming up for the fight to come.
- **Chiss** - Salute: Prompts nearby allies to stand at attention.

Comment: There are also some minor conversational differences that depend on your race, mostly humans calling you an alien, or fellow aliens talking about you as "us aliens" nothing that seems to affect any outcomes.